# ReactJS: Building a dynamic page

Tags: reactjs

Basically, I do not know what components will constitute a page. I want to be able to build a page given a list of React component names.

```
render() {
  let componentList = getComponentList({this.data.props.componentNameList})
  return(
    componentList.map((component) => {
      // Somehow call component.render or let the framework do it for me?
    }) 
  )
}
```

I would have numerous component name lists available to me during build time. So, I should be able to generate an appropriate bundle.js and bundle.css with the requires (webpack).

A specific list will be chosen during runtime based on type of page/user segments/ configuration etc.

And all this should be isomorphic.

Is this possible using React?

Am I thinking about this all wrong? I am very new to React.

Comment: The item needs to exist on page load or you will get "existence hell" problems.

Comment: Is the problem solved? If your problem is solved then you must mark the answer as accepted. This helps other people to find what they are looking for. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create each React Elements using [React.createElement()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) which takes a `string` or `ReactElement` parameter indicating the type of React component you want to create.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing as well, but not only I get Names of the components, I get their props as well (in JSON), then using createElement() - so all is dynamically created and I think this is what React does pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way in render do;

```js
let returnRadio = (
  <input
  ref="inputRef"
  type={inputType}
  style={inputSty}
  checked={radioChecked}
  value={radioValue}
  onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
)

let returnChecked = (
  <input
  ref="inputRef"
  type={inputType}
  style={inputSty}
  checked={checkedValue}
  onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} />
)

let returnColor = (
  <input
  type={inputType}
  ref="inputRef"
  style={inputSty}
  value={colorValue}
  onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
)

let returnNumber = (
  <input
  type={inputType}
  ref="inputRef"
  style={inputSty}
  value={numberValue}
  min={min} max={max} step={step}
  onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
)

let returnText = (
  <input
  type={inputType}
  ref="inputRef"
  style={inputSty}
  value={textValue}
  onChange={this.handleTextValueChange} />
)
let returnIt = {};
switch (inputType) {
  case 'checkbox': returnIt = returnChecked; break;
  case 'radio': returnIt = returnRadio; break;
  case 'color': returnIt = returnColor; break;
  case 'number':
  case 'range': returnIt = returnNumber; break;
  default: returnIt = returnText; break;
}

return (returnIt);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need a wrapper element, for example `<div>`, or `<ul>`. Then just use [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) in a `map()` method:

```js
render() {
  let componentList = getComponentList({this.data.props.componentNameList})
  return(
    <div>
    {componentList.map((component) => {
      return React.createElement(component);
    })} 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. This is how I was able to solve it:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let componentNames = ['ExampleA', 'ExampleB']
    let components = {}
    componentNames.map((componentName) => {
      components[componentName] = React.createFactory(require(`./${componentName}.js`))
    })
    return (
      <div>
        { components[componentNames[0]]() }
        { components[componentNames[1]]() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please note that all components should be in node_modules or in the "require" path.